# How enable nested mapping?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

using ES 6 and not being able to set my mapping correctly.
I have this doc:

```
{
    "_index": "entries_1",
    "_type": "elasticsearch-record",
    "_id": "3684",
    "_score": 5.355921,
    "_source": {
            "title": "My Title",
            "result": {
            "autor": [
                "fernando-fernandes"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And my mapping:

```
{
    "craft-entries_1": {
        "mappings": {
            "elasticsearch-record": {
                "properties": {
                    "result": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "enabled": false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I can't query `results.autor` with this:

```
{
    "query": {
            "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                { "term": { "result.autor": "fernando-fernandes" } }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried PUT this, but seems has no effect on mapping at all, even after I query again my mapping still appears as `enabled:false`, maybe I should mapping as object?

```
{
    "properties": {
        "result.autor": { 
            "type": "nested",
            "enabled": true
        }
    }
}
```

What i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your source document is not designed properly according to your mapping, it should be like this:

```
{
  "title": "My Title",
  "result": [
    {
      "autor": "fernando-fernandes"
    }
  ]
}
```

Since `result` is nested, it should be modeled as an array with elements inside.

So, delete your index, recreate it with your following mapping (you need to remove `enabled: false` as that's only for `object` types)

```
PUT craft-entries_1
{
    "mappings": {
        "elasticsearch-record": {
            "properties": {
                "result": {
                    "type": "nested"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, index your documents as I showed above, and then your query will work.

Comment: Thank you Val! But actually I can't change the document because it's automatically created by my CMS, if I delete the mapping and create my mapping again? Should work? And I'll have any impact on the existing documents?

Comment: What CMS are we talking about here?

Comment: Craft CMS and they have a plugin to ES, but it's not better delete all mapping and remake them?

Comment: You can delete the mapping and try again